# Impossible to log into git with powershell

Tags: git, powershell, github

I'm trying to push a project into a git repo but it's impossible to log in.
I'm using my git account username/password (100% sure, checked at least 10 times)
But log fails every time. This is what i get when trying to git push :

1. Username for 'http://www.github.com': ~MyUsername~
2. Password for 'http://~MyUsername~@www.github.com': ~MyPassword~
3. fatal: Authentification failed

I can log into github.com with them without any issue.
Thanks for any help in advance !

EDIT : exact same thing with Git Bash

Comment: How are you trying to log in? SSH?

Comment: As you mention powershell explicitely, does it work with Git Bash?

Comment: Have you got authentication keys and stuff set up?

Comment: Ni idea, it asks for it automatically when i try a push

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push via the HTTP protocol. You need to use HTTPS.

Comment: Just change the URL from `http://...` to `https://`. You can open the file `.git/config` to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I changed the adress from http://www.github.com to http://github.com
Dunnow if it's the clean way to do it but it works.